# I want to select and display month and date between two dates in yii2 framework

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE dob BETWEEN '2005-01-01' AND  '2005-12-31'
```

for example the dates between 2005-01-01 and 2005-12-31. I want to show like

01-01 02-01 03-01 ... ... ... 12-31

Answer (score 0):

use `group_concat` and `DATE_FORMAT`

```
select group_concat(DATE_FORMAT(dob,'%d-%m') SEPARATOR  ' ') from employee WHERE dob BETWEEN '2005-01-01' AND  '2005-12-31'
```

If you need unique dates then you can use `DISTINCT` as below

```
select group_concat(DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(dob,'%d-%m') SEPARATOR  ' ') from employee WHERE dob BETWEEN '2005-01-01' AND  '2005-12-31'
```

Comment: `Distinct` might be needed to avoid duplicates.

Comment: yes, if any duplicate then need to use `DISTINCT ` in `group_concat`